# reading vm properties from a shell script XshowSettings

Tags: bash, shell, virtual-machine, system, java-7

I am trying to capture the output of `java -XshowSettings | grep file.encoding` but it is not working. I am trying to read a property of `java -XshowSettings` from a Unix shell script. Normally, it is easy to ready a property by using e.g. `printenv | grep JAVA_HOME` but in case of `java -XshowSetting`, grep does not work.

So, I want something like this `java -XshowSetting | grep file.encoding`, but it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: What is the error that you've received for running `java -XshowSetting | grep file.encoding`?

Comment: by executing this command from the bash command line - all the parameters have been printed out on the console but NOT the one greped parameter "file.encoding". // executed from GIT BASH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem

```
java -XshowSettings 2>&1 | grep file.encoding
```

You need to combine the standard output and standard error to capture the results. Read more [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20472/205484).